# Displaying multiple RTF strings in a FlowDocument

Tags: .net, wpf, rtf, flowdocument

I have multiple RTF strings that I wish to merge and display for printing, I guess using a flow document. I have seen many examples of taking one RTF string (stream) and then using a TextRange object to map that to the flow document, but this will only map one RTF string to the flow document, what's the best way to add multiple pieces of RTF together in a document along with other FlowDocument type things such as embedding images?